# Restoring disk space after a failed sort command applied to a large text file

Tags: sorting, ubuntu, diskspace

After applying `sort` command on Ubuntu to 89GB text file I've got a message that there is no disk space, after about 30 minutes. As I can see the space used by the output file is 0.
The command I used is like `sort myfile.txt>outfile.txt`.
I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.
I have no clue which files or folders are taking the space.

Answer (score 1):

Your temporary folder has run out of space (/tmp). The intermediate sort results are written to $TMPDIR or /tmp and then merged into result file. You can change the default temp folder with -T, --temporary-directory flag.

For example, if you want to use your current working directory:

```
sort -T $(pwd) /var/log/syslog > syslog.sorted
```

To see all the docs for the sort command use:

```
man sort
```